# Error on initial push notification subscription

Tags: mobile-application, notification, error-message, errors, push-notification

Does it make sense to inform the user with an error message when initial registration to push notifications fails?

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense to inform the user since there was already an initial registration process. However, the manner/language to deliver the message should be sorta different from the way a typical error message would be delivered to the user.

Maybe like "Hey there, we couldn't add push notification at this time, please try again".